# Using jQuery to delete an option value from a select box using the delete key

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Using jQuery, how can one remove an option value from a select box using on the keypress of the delete key? Here is the HTML part which I need to use for my process:

```
<select id="cars">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what do you want to delete?

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Comment: It's not that hard so what have you tried???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#select").keydown(function(event) {

    if(event.which != 46) { return }

    var sel = $(this);

    var val = sel.val();

    if(val != "") { sel.find("option[value="+val+"]").remove(); }

});
```

Comment: or just `$(this).find('option:selected').remove();`